# Dropwizard DataSourceFactory on Heroku with just DATABASE_URL

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, dropwizard, dokku

I'm trying to deploy a Dropwizard-app on heroku, and on dokku ("open-source heroku"), but I'm stuck at the configuration of the database. The reason is that I'm only provided a one-line connection url from Heroku:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:SOME_PASSWORD@172.17.0.1:5432/lolipop
```

What's the best way to get a DataSourceFactory from this into my Configuration?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import io.dropwizard.Configuration;
import io.dropwizard.db.DataSourceFactory;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.List;

public class MyConfiguration extends Configuration {
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private DataSourceFactory database = new DataSourceFactory();

    private List<String> allowedOrigins;

    @JsonProperty("database")
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
        return database;
    }

    @JsonProperty("database")
    public void setDataSourceFactory(DataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory) {
        this.database = dataSourceFactory;
    }
}
```

I would want the config file to look like this

```
database:
    driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: ${DATABASE_URL}
```

Comment: Another solution will come in Dropwizard 0.9.0, when usernames are no longer required https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/1260

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` on Heroku as described in [Connecting to Relational Databases on Heroku with Java](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url)

However, if you'd prefer to parse the `DATABASE_URL` youself (since it's the canonical representation), you could use the [heroku-jdbc](https://github.com/jkutner/heroku-jdbc) library.